# Binding with multiple textblock properties

Tags: xaml, uwp, textblock, converters

I have a requirement where text block should turn red,bold,underline and font should become bigger while validating on save button.

Below is my xamlcode

```
<TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Foreground="{x:Bind Model.FirstNameError, Converter={StaticResource ErrorColorConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            FontStyle="{x:Bind Model.FirstNameError, Converter={StaticResource ErrorFontStyleConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                            FontSize="{x:Bind Model.FirstNameError, Converter={StaticResource ErrorFontSizeConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"                            
                    <Run Text="First Name" TextDecorations="{x:Bind Model.FirstNameError, Converter={StaticResource TextUnderlineConverter},Mode=OneWay}" />                    
                </TextBlock>
```

Converter code:i have created multiple converters like below for ErrorColorConverter,ErrorFontSizeConverter and TextUnderlineConverter

```
 public class ErrorFontStyleConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return  FontStyle.Italic;
            else
                return FontStyle.Normal;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

It works exactly the way i need, but i need some suggestions on if this can be done in better way?, do we have any ways to simplify this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ConverterParameter` and receive them all from a single converter

```
 <TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind FirstNameError,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource ErrorToFont},ConverterParameter=foreground}"
               FontStyle="{x:Bind FirstNameError,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource ErrorToFont},ConverterParameter=fontstyle}"
               FontWeight="{x:Bind FirstNameError,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource ErrorToFont},ConverterParameter=fontweight}">
```

//Converter

```
public class ErrorFontConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "fontstyle")
                return (bool)value ? Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Italic : Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Normal;
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "foreground")
                return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            else
                return (bool)value ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```